# Setting useState hook at first click returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I'm having trouble setting the taskID at my useState hook.

once I click the button it returns me undefined but once I refresh the whole page it works perfectly.

I was suspecting that the reason for this was the way I map arrays because it's nested.

here's my code.

```
const [task_id, setGetid] = useState('')

    return (
        <div>
            {cart && Object.keys(cart).map(state => {
                return (
                    <div className='h-auto max-h-[60vh] w-[50vw] overflow-y-auto flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-center items-center mt-5 gap-4' key={cart[state]._id}>
                        {cart[state]?.list && Object.keys(cart[state]?.list).map(task => {
                            return (
                                <div className='bg-[#1c1e21] h-[6vh] w-[48vw] relative drop-shadow-md flex flex-row items-center justify-end' key={cart[state]?.list[task]?._id}>
                                    <span className='ml-5 text-white font-Poppins text-1xl absolute left-0'>{cart[state]?.list[task]?.task}</span>
                                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(patchHandler)}>
                                        <button type='submit' className='bg-[#01313d] text-md font-Poppins text-white drop-shadow-md h-[4vh] w-auto flex flex-row items-center pl-3 pr-3 mr-2 gap-1'>
                                            <FaEdit /> Edit
                                        </button>
                                    </form>
                                    <form onSubmit={deleteHandler}>
                                        <button type='submit' onClick={() => {
                                            setGetid(cart[state]?.list[task]?._id) // setState task ID returns undefined at first click and works perfectly after refreshing the whole page
                                        }} className='bg-[#01313d] text-md font-Poppins text-white drop-shadow-md h-[4vh] w-auto flex flex-row items-center pl-3 pr-3 mr-2 gap-1'>
                                            <FaTrash /> Remove
                                        </button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got an `onSubmit` event handler on the second form, but also an `onClick` event handler on the `button type="submit"` in that form. IDK what behavior that causes (i.e. what order do the callbacks get called, or does only one of them fire?), but try refactoring so you only use `onSubmit` on the form, or if the behavior of submitting is supposed to be different from the behavior of clicking the button, then the button should not be `type="submit"`.

I'm not sure what behavior you are currently getting because you say when you click the button "it returns undefined" -- what do you mean? Is there a "TypeError cannot read property of undefined" error? Or does it set `task_id` to undefined? This is the kind of thing that would make a clearer question.

BTW - you can probably just use `cart.map(state =>`, `state.list.map(task =>`, and `task._id` when you loop.

Comment: what I mean is my useState task_id receives undefined at the first click of the button and then If I refresh the whole page then click the button again it returns me the task_id I've been looking for so it basically requires me to refresh the whole page first before clicking the button to receive the id.

Comment: Does this consistently happen every time? I don't have enough info to know why that is, but you could start with fixing the problem with the `onClick` and `onSubmit` conflicting with each other. Try to learn more about what's going on by console logging the `_id` before passing it to `setGetid`. Notice all the `?.` operators; maybe another variable is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

With your implementation, when you click the button both `deleteHandler` and `setGetid(cart[state]?.list[task]?._id)` will run.

Why do you want to do that? you can simply move `setGetid(cart[state]?.list[task]?._id)` to the `deleteHandler` function if you really want to execute both logics, because here, the issue of

> returns me undefined but once I refresh the whole page it works perfectly

Should be related to the `e.prevenDefault()` of the `deleteHandler` function cutting in between. so if you get rid of the `onClick` event handler and move its code to `deleteHandler` it should work as expected.